# the topological subspace $S(n) = \{A\in C^{n\times n}: A^* = A\}$ is connected by trajectories under the Frobenius metric?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have this idea: notice that the path component of the identities all $S(n)$ is because of how $S(n)$ is defined. So let $X_n, Y_n \in S(n) $ then $ X_n \sim_h I_n $ and $ I_n \sim_h Y_n $ then $ X_n \sim_h Y_n $ but I don't know how to prove the component of the trajectory of the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

A Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues.

Define a path connecting a diagonal matrix with real entries to the identity matrix such that all elements of the path are diagonal matrices with real entries.

Comment: I don't think you can because of the matrix of zeros

Comment: Why? The zero matrix is Hermitian too.